# .Net Core 3 worker service application with plugins with constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, .net-core, plugins, constructor

I'am building windows service with re loadable plugins using .Net Core 3.
I started with Worker Service project template and added plugins feature using recommendations in Microsoft article [Create a .NET Core application with plugins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support). My plugins use external dependencies and everything is load fine. Also, my solution can load/unload plugins without restarting service and for now all works fine. 
Now I want to add parameters to plugin constructor (at this moment plugin constructor is parameter less) which will be resolved by DI from service, but without success. I need to pass ex. ILogerFactory, DbContext to plugin via constructor injection.

To create plugin instance I'm using

```
ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(this._serviceProvider, pluginType)
```

this._serviceProvider is constructor parameter in method from which plugins are created and it is correctly resolved from DI:

```
public TransformFile(ILogger<TransformFile> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

If I have plugin constructor like this

```
public TransformationPlugin(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
```

exception is thrown

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to activate 'Transformation.TransformationPlugin'.
```

If I have plugin constructor like this

```
public TransformationPlugin(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

i receive serviceProvider with 45 registered services but GetService returns null for every service.
If I stop execution in plugin constructor in Immediate Window I'm able to resolve ex. ILoggerFactory.
I try both with and without

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

in plugin .csproj but result is same.
Also in plugins .csproj I have `<Private>false</Private>` for project in which interface is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. From documentation was clear that for two types to be treated as same they must be loaded from the same assembly. My wrong assumption was that Microsoft.* and Systems.* assemblies will be loaded in the same way as is shared project loaded. After some investigation, I found that these assemblies in the main program are loaded from the bin folder but in the plugin, they are loaded from C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages...
The reason for this is how AssemblyDependencyResolver works.
So in PluginAssemblyLoadContext in Load overridden method I replaced

```
string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
        if (assemblyPath != null)
        {
            return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
        }
```

with

```
if (!assemblyName.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !assemblyName.FullName.StartsWith("System", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
            if (assemblyPath != null)
            {
                return this.LoadFromFile(assemblyPath);
            }
        }
```

and now in both main program and plugin Microsoft.* and System.* assemblies are shared and types (ILoggerFactory, IConfiguration, ...) are treated as same.